# Change font locally in Beamer

Tags: fonts, grouping, type

How do I change the font locally for one word in Beamer? I want to type the Greek letter Phi in uppercase and lowercase. The uppercase in Beamer show
[image]
but I want to have it looks like the varPhi which is [image] . Is there a way (I am thinking of changing the font type) so that the Phi also looks like a straight up varPhi? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Related? Or maybe a duplicate. [How do you swap the commands for two symbols?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/50360) or maybe [How to get Beamer Math to look like Article Math](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/34265).

Comment: Thanks to @Alan Munn. The second discussion you refer to is the answer I was looking for. Only need to add \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} to the preamble and everything works perfectly now. Thank a lot!

Comment: Yes, it is the one!